Setting DataFrame Divisions with Query Expressions
I think it's pretty clear to me why ddf.divisions = <some_divisions> is no longer supported but what is not clear to me is how i can efficiently do this now. Any thoughts?
The above code results in the following error:
        if key in columns and key not in [
            "divisions",
            "dask",
            "_name",
            "_meta",
            "_expr",
        ]:
            self[key] = value
        else:
>           object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
E           AttributeError: can't set attribute 'divisions'


How are you building your DataFrame? There are many methods where divisions can be specified.

We have a collection of pandas dfs each with a timestamp index, where the divs are based on a cat. variable. This is created by calling set_index() on the cat. variable, and then calling map_partitions() to set the index of each df to the timestamp col. This is a hack due to the lack of multiindex, but the goal is to apply repeated timeseries operations on each individual pandas df using map_partitions. The issue we now face is with pd.concat() on multiple dfs of this form. Previously, we could clear the divs, call pd.concat(), and then reset the divs. This is no longer possible

Can you elaborate a bit more about what you want to do?
Divisions are slowly losing in importance with the Query Planner, we can now make many decisions based not he expression tree that previously required divisions. So getting a little bit more context with what you are dealing with would be very helpful.

We have a collection of pandas dfs each with a timestamp index, where the divs are based on a cat. variable.  This is created by calling set_index() on the cat. variable, and then calling map_partitions() to set the index of each df to the timestamp col.  This is a hack due to the lack of multiindex, but the goal is to apply repeated timeseries operations on each individual pandas df using map_partitions.
The issue we now face is with pd.concat() on multiple dfs of this form.  Previously, we could clear the divs, call pd.concat(), and then reset the divs.  This is no longer possible.
